# SQL command not properly ended, on an insert/on duplicate

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I've isolated my problem down to this code, which is giving me the error message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" for the on duplicate key line.

I'm trying to insert rows unless they have a duplicate key, in which case I want to update them instead. Something like [insert...select](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html) and [on duplicate key update](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

I can see it must be a syntax problem, but I don't normally work with SQL so any help is appreciated.

```
insert into "tableB" ("col1", "col2")
select      "tableA"."colX", "tableA"."colY"
from        "tableA"
on duplicate key update "tableB"."col1" = "tableA"."colX";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO tableB b
USING tableA a
    ON (b.col1 = a.colX)
WHEN     MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET b.col2 = a.colY
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( col1, col2 )
VALUES(a.colX, a.colY);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fd72/1)

Note: this is presuming your key between the two tables is col1 and colx.

Comment: How is MERGE different from INSERT...SELECT? i.e. is there anything I should be aware of before making the change?

Comment: Edited to add: because I made the change and it's working :)

Comment: @stringy - it's mostly different because Oracle doesn't have the `on duplicate key` syntax.